# How to extract session value from apache shiro login form?

Tags: java, forms, authentication, servlets, shiro

I have a login form that gets redirected to a servlet upon success. I am using apache shiro for authentication and I am trying to extract the username submitted by my form so I can use it in my servlet. I'm wondering if shiro already has these values stored in a session. if so, how do I extract these so I can use them in my servlet? I have tried putting a form action on my form and extracting the username using `request.getParameter("username")` in my servlet but it doesn't seem to work when using shiro. I have read the shiro documentation and read similar questions also. I'm still unsure about where to actually configure and extract session variables. Is it in `shiro.ini` or in my servlet?

**shiro.ini**

```html
jdbcRealm= org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from user where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role from userroles where userID = (select id FROM user WHERE username = ?)
;jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery  = ??????

ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
;ds.password = shiro
ds.databaseName = shiro
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 5000

authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.usernameParam = username
authc.passwordParam = password
;authc.rememberMeParam = rememberMe
authc.successUrl = /secret/SecretStockServlet
logout.redirectUrl = /login.jsp

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc 
/secret/** = authc 
/logout = logout
```

**Log in Form**

```html
<form name="loginform" id ="loginform" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <p>Please fill in this form to log in.</p>
            <hr>

            <label for="username"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="username" id="username" required>

            <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>
            <hr>

            <button type="submit" class="loginbtn">Log in</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container signin">
            <p>Need to register? <a href="register.jsp">Sign up</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**/secret/SecretStockServlet**

```html
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String address;
        try {

            List<SalesStock> list = stockRepository.getAllSalesStock();
            address = "/secret/stock.jsp";

            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            Session session = (Session) currentUser.getSession();

            request.setAttribute("list", list);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            address = "/error.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JSPs you could use the [Shiro Tag lib](https://shiro.apache.org/jsp-tag-library.html)

OR

Calling `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()` should return the Subject's username.

OR

You can likely get the info you need from calling `Subject.getPrincpal()` too, though this depends on the implementation of your realms.